# Deploy/Download Profile ListView

Tags: rest-api, metadata-api, metadata

I need to deploy & download a Profile ListView, it seems typically a ListView would be included in the object's XML, but when I try to download this it gives me this error:

`package.xml - Can't retrieve non-customizable CustomObject named: Profile`

Which seems odd because an account will download if I specify that instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>36.0</version>
</Package>
```

Considering these are both standard objects, why does it work for one but not the other? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm

Is there another method I can use to deploy this, or am I do something incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there another method I can use to deploy this ...

No.

> or am I do something incorrectly?

No.

This is missing from the metadata API. You cannot retrieve the list view for any object that does not allow customization, even if that object supports list views. Other examples include ApexClass, ApexTrigger, and TraceFlag.

Comment: Thank you again, is there by chance a list of objects that are not customizable?

Comment: @JacobHacker I don't think I've ever seen a comprehensive list of objects you cannot customize. Generally anything under Setup > Customize or Setup > Create > Objects counts a customizable object, anything else does not. Most of the non-customizable objects are things like share tables and audit tables. If you found such a list, I wouldn't mind editing it in.

Comment: @JacobHacker also, a lacuna is a gap or missing part.

Comment: I see, I thought it was spanish, but it might just not be common in the midwest.